# Shell script for automated kernel compilation

Tags: arch-linux, kernel-modules, make

I am trying to write a shell script to build a custom kernel on Arch Linux.

I have succeeded to do write all the steps described in the Arch Linux kernel compilation page:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernels/Compilation/Traditional

But I am stuck on the last step to "Recompile VirtualBox guest module":

```
We need to do one more thing before we reboot to our new kernel. We have to recompile the VirtualBox guest module so that things like screen resizing will still work when we reboot to the new kernel.

First, make sure you have the virtualbox-guest-dkms package installed:

sudo pacman -S virtualbox-guest-dkms
If you have it installed already, pacman will ask you if you want to reinstall. Say no, but note the version number of the module.

Recompile the VirtualBox guest module by running:

sudo dkms remove  vboxguest/version-number -k kernel-version
sudo dkms install vboxguest/version-number -k kernel-version

Substitute your vboxguest version number and your kernel version string.
```

If I run `sudo pacman -S virtualbox-guest-dkms` in the terminal, I would get following output:

```
warning: virtualbox-guest-dkms-4.3.26-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) virtualbox-guest-dkms-4.3.26-2

Total Installed Size:  5.26 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

If I choose to install it, it will tell me to proceed installation by running the command -- `dkms install vboxguest/version-number`

Since I want to make the shell script as robust as possible, I would need to do the following:

1. If the guest module has already been installed, just grap the version-number from the pacman query and exit.

Then I just need to run the following two commands:

```
sudo dkms remove  vboxguest/version-number -k kernel-version
sudo dkms install vboxguest/version-number -k kernel-version
```

2. If guest module is not installed, do installation and grap the `dkms install vboxguest/version-number` command from the pacman query and exit.

Run `sudo dkms install vboxguest/version-number`.

The rest is the same as the scenario one above.

**The first scenario is the most likely one.**

Could someone please give me a hand on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use `expac` to query the current required version: `expac -S '%v' virtualbox-guest-dkms` and compare to what you have installed: `expac -Q '%v' virtualbox-guest-dkms`; if those numbers are not the same, run `pacman`... Having said that, you are better off just putting a `depends` in the PKGBUILD and letting `makepkg` work it out.

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie to linux system, could you please elaborate on PKGBUILD a bit more? Thanks @jasonwryan

Comment: See the [Arch Wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pkgbuild).